# Xrdp not working with CentOS7. Is there any alternatives?

Tags: centos, gnome, remote-desktop, gdm, xrdp

Every time I try using xrdp, I get a message that says "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." and "A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again." I feel like it is an issue with gdm but I'm not sure. It authenticates, but when it tries to load the screen, I get the white screen with the sad face. I then click on logout and a black screen appears. Any help on how to fix this or any alternatives t xrdp?

Im trying to use windows remote desktop to connect to centos 7

Answer (score 1):

You could try FreeRDP, which takes a different approach to the problem.

You could also try the workaround (hackish) detailed in this post:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=392184

PS: I am not going to transcribe the hack because I cannot confirm it actually works

Answer (score 0):

You could use NX / FreeNX by **NoMachine**.

Here their wiki on the subject: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX